# Install OS on Galaxy S4 w/ broken screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, linux, operating-system, physical-damage

I have an Samsung Galaxy S4 with a broken screen (no touch input and no visual output); it's been sitting in my closet for months, but it still charges & boots. Now, I want to put it to good use by installing a new OS (e.g. Ubuntu and/or Android) and turning it into a server on my home network (the battery would act as a convenient UPS). However, since the screen is broken I can't access any menus and can't give it any input.

Is there a way to access this phone to perform a fresh OS install (e.g. via USB)?

*Note: This question was originally [posted](https://superuser.com/questions/1207577/install-os-on-galaxy-s4-w-broken-screen) on SuperUser, but migrated here because it was off-topic for that community.*

Comment: Possible to do that. Bit you will need to manually put it in flash mode then using​ Odin, flash a new OS

Comment: The problem here is, since most if not all ROMs have USB debugging turned off by default, even if you managed to install something while in the blind, you can't interact with it after booting it up (you can't even navigate past the setup wizard).

Comment: @andyYan Exactly! So is all hope lost?